# Replace all occurrences on the page vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, replace

So, I have multiple components coming from multiple folders in one component and I'm trying to create a method that would act globally and try to replace words with certain replacement.

For example.

```
<template>
<div>
    Users Area
</div>
<div class="row" v-if="hasSiteData">
    <div class="col">
        <admin-overview-component :isLoading="isLoading" :site="site"></admin-overview-component>
    </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
//includes and all.
</script>
```

This template has `Users` word multiple times also, in `admin-overview-component` component too. there are API calls as well which takes time to complete and display data.

In jquery, we would use `$(document).ready()` I can use it here but it would only change whatever it in the laravel blade view not in vue components.

I would like to change `Users` to `Members` in whole page even in different components. How should I do it?

Comment: What about using "search & replace" (IDE feature) on all concerned files ?

Comment: Using app, there can be many strings that user would want to replace. It's like translation on php but I want to do it on vuejs as a feature.

Comment: If you're wanting this on a live page, in Vue you're realistically going to have to make all the instances of "Users" dynamic. The most succinct way to do that is probably using a state management solution of some sort like Vuex, so you could update the Vuex state and then it would in turn update all instances of the value in all your respective components. Alternatively, you could just use props, but that could get really messy fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/)